# Specialize class for Base and all Derived

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have a Base-class and a derived class. I would like to design a Class C that reacts differently when a base or derived object is handed over like this:

```
template<typename T>
class Base {};
class Derived: public Base<int>{}

template<typename T>
class C
{
public:
    static int f(T&& arg) {return 1;};
};
// Specialize C, not the function
template<typename T>
class C<T>
{
public:
    static int f(T&& arg) {return 2;};
};

template<typename T>
int function(T&& arg) {
    return C<T>::f(std::forward<T>(arg));
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << function(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << function(Base<float>()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << function(Derived()) << std::endl;
}
```

This is supposed to print:

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 2

Is there a way that I can do this with specializing the class `C` and not the function. In reality I just hand over the type C and everything happens out of my reach.
To clearify, the implementation of function may look like that but I can't really tell. All I know is the signature of f: `int f(T&&)`; And that I have to have a class C that has a function of that signature.

Comment: You probably want `std::is_convertible` and `std::enable_if`.

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail? I can't see how to do it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Through Specialization of function():**

Example code first:

```
template< class T >
struct Base
{};

struct Child : Base<int>
{    };

template<typename T>
class C1
{
public:
    static int f(T&& arg) {return 1;}
};

template<typename T>
class C2
{
public:
    static int f(T&& arg) {return 2;}
};

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if< std::is_base_of<Base<int>, T>::value, int >::type function(T&& arg) 
{
    return C2<T>::f(std::forward<T>(arg));
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if< !std::is_base_of<Base<int>, T >::value, int >::type function(T&& arg) 
{
    return C1<T>::f(std::forward<T>(arg));
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << function(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << function(Base<int>()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << function(Child()) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

*Why:*

So the split here is that I've written two versions of function(). The return type of function() looks a little hairy but the first version will be compiled if T has Base< int > as a base type. Otherwise the second version will be used.

std::enable_if<> is a neat tool which causes the template expansion to fail if its condition is not met. In this case we cause the template expansion to fail if T does not have Base< int > as a base class. In the case that the template expansion fails the compiler continues to look for another version of function() which will compile.

C1 and C2 are then two different objects with C2 being used if T has Base as a child, otherwise C1 is used.

**Through Specialization of C:**

```
template< class BaseArgument >
Base< BaseArgument > get_Base_type_of( Base< BaseArgument >&& );

template< class T >
struct has_Base
{
  typedef char yes;
  typedef long no;

  template< typename T1 >
  static yes Check( decltype( get_Base_type_of( declval<T1>() ) )* );

  template< typename T1 >
  static no Check( ... );

  static const bool value = sizeof( decltype( Check<T>(0) ) ) == sizeof( yes ) ;
};

template< typename T, typename Placeholder = void >
class C
{
public:
    static int f(T&& arg) {return 1;};
};

template<typename T>
class C< T, typename std::enable_if< has_Base<T>::value >::type >
{
public:
    static int f(T&& arg) {return 2;};
};
```

Comment: Here's the deal though: It should specialize on C, not on the function. Should mentioned that... I thought it was clear. C is provided by the user, the function is already defined. I don't know how to specialize C so that this has the correct effect.

Comment: I have added an example of how one might specialize C instead at the end of the post. It does require an extra template parameter though.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but this example only specializes for Base<int>. But I want to specilize every Base<Q>. The extra template parameter is not a problem, I have full control over C.

Comment: @WorldSEnder Then just give `C` another template argument: `template< typename T, typename U, typename Placeholder = void >` and use `std::is_base_of<U, T>::value`

Comment: I will just guess you meant `std::is_base_of<Base<U>, T>::value`. That throws a compiler error: `template parameters not used in partial specialization: Q`.

Comment: OK. I have just amended my answer (apologies to 0x499602D2 - I posted and then updated and saw you had a reply). This has been tested under GCC and works for any Base<T>

Comment: Additionally my working day is over. I am going home :) Good luck with your coding! I hope these answers helped some.

Comment: That looks great... with C++0x I totally forgot about good old SFINAE. Thank you so much